# What is the correct way to add elements to a csr_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a csr_matrix, let's say I called:

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
mat = ss.csr.csr_matrix((50, 100))
```

Now I want to modify some of the values on this matrix. I call:

```
mat[0,1]+=1
```

And I get:

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
```

I need only to set a few values (at the scale of the matrix at last) just after the creation of the matrix. Later on I will only read the columns or do element-wise operations on the whole matrix (like `.log1p()`)

What would be the correct way to do that ? Currently I can just ignore the warning, but there may be a better way, that don't yield a warning.

Comment: CSR and CSC are the preferred formats for quick linear algebra calculations.  You typically construct your matrix as COO, LIL or DOK, convert it to CSC or CSR only once, then do the expensive math on it. It would help to understand better your use case: what do you want to do with the matrix? Do you need to add new data in between expensive operations, or can the additions be batched at the start?

Comment: edited, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Create a [COO matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), add the values to it, then convert it to a CSC or CSR matrix if there is a speed advantage for your operations. If all you are after are elementwise operations, COO will probably be fine. If you want to extract columns choose CSC, if rows CSR.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the appearance of warnings.  The default is to show them once during a run, and then be silent.  You can change that to raise an error, be completely silent, or issue the warning every time.

A common way of creating a sparse matrix is to create the 3 `coo` style arrays, with all nonzero values.  Then make a `coo` matrix, or csr directly (it takes the same style of input).

`coo` format doesn't have indexing, so you can't do `M[i,j]=1` anyways.  But `csr` does implement it.  I think the warning is there to discourage multiple changes (in a loop) not one or two.

Changing the sparsity of a `csr` matrix requires recalculating the whole set of attributes (data and index pointers).  That's why its expensive.  I haven't done timings but it may be almost as expensive as making the array fresh.

`lil` is supposed to be better for incremental assignment.  It keeps its data in lists of lists, and inserting values into lists is fast.  But converting `csr` to `lil` and back takes time, so I wouldn't do it for just a few additions.

Comment: I don't want to change warning appearance, I want to do things right. Currently I don't ask for changing the sparsity but it seems it happens anyway, and I am wondering why.

Comment: Some forms of addition can also trigger this warning.

Comment: I see that, but is it as bad as if I was reformating the whole matrix to not sparse or is it just a false alert ? Making the 3 vectors as you suggest is actually not that cheap, so I don't want to switch to that if it doesn't make things better.

Comment: How are you constructing the array to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Create sparse matrix.
graph = csr_matrix((10, 10))
# Change sparse matrix.
graph[(1, 1)] = 0      # --- SLOW --- ^1
# Do some calculations.
graph += graph
```

Or:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

# Create sparse matrix.
graph = lil_matrix((10, 10))
# Change sparse matrix.
graph[(1, 1)] = 0
# Do some calculations.
graph += graph         # --- SLOW --- ^2
```

Combine the strengths of both:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, lil_matrix

# Create sparse matrix.
graph = lil_matrix((10, 10))
# Change sparse matrix.
graph[(1, 1)] = 0
# Done with changes to graph. Convert to csr.
graph = csr_matrix(graph)
# Do some calculations.
graph += graph
```

Don't take "`--- SLOW ---`" as a one-size fits all commandment! It's just a warning that in with some data sets you should be aware that there may be faster, more efficient ways, of doing things. For other data sets this would only make your code harder to read and maintain without any performance benefit.

1: "SLOW" as per warning:

> `/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:82: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.`

2: "SLOW" as per warning in [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html):

> **Disadvantages of the LIL format:**
> arithmetic operations LIL + LIL are slow (consider CSR or CSC)

Comment: And, yes, I realize this is an old post. However, it wasn't answered and search engines dropped me here when I got the same error so I figured it was worth creating an explanation of what was going on.